# How can I set different html lang attribute for different countries?

Tags: html, language, page-attributes

My WordPress theme header.php html language attitude

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
```

All page html language attitude :

```
<html lang="en-US">
```

But I have some pages for different countries. I want to use different html lang attitude code for each country page with single header.php

For example:

English page language attitude  : `<html lang="en">`

Portuguese page language attitude : `<html lang="pt">`

Spanish page language attitude : `<html lang="es">`

Indonesian page language attitude : `<html lang="id">`

Vietnamese page language attitude : `<html lang="vi">`

etc...

How can I do it?

Comment: Keep in mind that countries and languages don't map on to eachother. e.g. what if I a british person loads your site while on holiday in spain, or proxied through another country? Now I can't understand your site. Or a Portuguese person living in the USA? Or a person from the UK who only speaks welsh but is presented with an english page?